# to delete windows lumia 630 whatsapp data

Tags: whatsapp, nokia-lumia-630

You are giving such a wrong answer. Windows Phone(Lumia 630) don't have a file manager. Problem. Then how can I go to this folder. My problem is the WhatsApp data in my phone is 2GB. I want to delete that data. Please tell me how to delete that data,tell proper answer.

Comment: Please clarify your question, and link to the "wrong answer" you're referring to, if it helps provide context. Right now it's a bit difficult to figure out what your issue is.

Comment: I assume that you are asking how to clear the app data associated with WhatsApp as it cannot be located in FIle Manager. This data is mainy your chat history and you can clear the app data by clearing unwanted chats or email/backup and clear other chats.

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect the phone to a PC
2. Delete WhatsApp folder on your phone and SD card
3. Uninstall WhatsApp and reinstall it